# Matrix algebras

Tags: ring-theory, modules

Let $k$ be any field, then we know that every finite dimensional semi simple algebra $A$ is isomorphic to a direct product of matrix algebras with entries over a division ring.

Assume that we require that in the decomposition into indecomposable submodules of $A$ none of the factors repeat. Can we guarantee then that $A$ is a direct product of division rings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. In that case, the homogeneous components are just simple modules. The simple components of the ring are precisely the endomorphism rings of the homogeneous components.

The endomorphism ring of a simple component must be a division ring by Schur's lemma. When there are multiple copies of a simple module appearing, you get nontrivial matrix rings.

Comment: @user10 You seem to know a lot about semisimple algebras, so let's try this. Have you run across the fact that their indecomposable modules are simple yet? All modules of a semisimple algebra are direct sums of simple modules. Therefore if a module is indecomposable, it certainly can't be a sum of two or more simple modules :) If you're not familiar with this property of the modules of semisimple rings, then I can elaborate.